# Asp.net MVC strange caching behavior

Tags: asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer, caching, browser-cache

I've got a controller that prepares a [menu sprite from a bunch of PNG images](http://australia.seaeagle.com/Sprite/MenuPNGImage/5). Since this is a CPU intensive process, and the images don't really change, I've set an OutputCache attribute on the controller as follows:

```
        [OutputCache(Duration = Int32.MaxValue)]
    public ActionResult MenuPNGImage()
    {
        MenuSprite ms = MenuSprite.BuildFromImages();
        return File(ms.PNGImageBytes, "image/png");
    }
```

I want to accomplish two things. First, cache the image on the server in RAM so it doesn't have to be recreated. This works like a charm. Second, I would like browsers to cache it locally so it doesn't have to be reloaded between requests.

When I request the image in Chrome, FireFox or Opera everything works fine. MVC sends the following header:

```
Cache-Control: max-age=0
```

Chrome gets the message and doesn't request the image on subsequent requests the server responds with a 304 (not modified) response.

But when I requrest the image in IE, MVC sends down a no-cache header for some reason:

```
Pragma: no-cache
```

Not surprisingly, IE requests the image on every subsequent page load. Of course, it's cached in RAM on the server so there is no overhead to create the image, but it does consume bandwidth to send it down the wire.

Is there any reason why this behavior would be default in MVC? I assume that MS would want it to perform better in IE, not worse.

Comment: Is there anything different about the request that IE sends to the server? Do you have IE set to not cache data, and request new each time? Have you reproduced this on multiple instances of IE, or just one?

Comment: I tried on two instances IE11, one running on Win7 and one on Win8 and got the same response - neither browser caches the image. Chrome, on the other hand, works fine on both the Win7 and Win8 machine.